# List of Historic Latin Mathematical Terms?

Tags: terminology, math-history

I am wanting to read some original mathematics literature in Latin (specifically Newton's De Analysi).  However, I was wondering if there was a list of specifically mathematical terminology that I should be aware of (i.e., Latin words whose meaning have a different meaning than their usual, dictionary meaning when dealing with mathematics).  I would appreciate links to any repository of terminology.

Comment: This might be better suited for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) (even though it is not off-topic here too!).

Comment: At [this site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/400/where-to-find-ancient-mathematics-in-latin) there are similar questions.

Comment: I had a look at Newton''s text (first 9 pages) http://www.newtonproject.ox.ac.uk/view/texts/normalized/NATP00204. Although I didn't read is completely, my impression is that you will not find any "ambiguous" terrninology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have asked, here I am providing some links

$1.~$ http://platonicrealms.com/encyclopedia/Latin-terms-and-phrases-in-math

$2.~$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_letters_used_in_mathematics

$3.~$ https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/frivs/latin/latin-dict-full.html

$4.~$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematics

I think it may help you a little bit.

Comment: There is no scope of downvote, as OP wants some links relating the matter. Is not it ? So please ...

Comment: *as OP wants some links* --- (+1) I agree, although I suspect the information supplied in the comments will be more useful.

Comment: I agree with them, but the links those are provided by me are also provide the answer too.

Comment: The first two are about latin-based terms used in contemporary math. The third is a generic Latin dictionary, and the fourth is about the general history of math. None seem to relate to the issues that would be faced trying to read old mathematical literature in original Latin. Hence the down-vote. This was the accepted answer so I guess I'm wrong but I really don't see how these will help. Did any of the up-voters actually open the links and think about how/if they answer the question?

Comment: So according to you, what is the appropriate one ? I think this links will help one to read the old mathematical literature in Latin. If you want totally converted mathematical literature in Latin, then it is a different matter. And I don't think that OP  meant it.